# How to deal with focusout event not firing when Submit is clicked?

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

I have a .cshmtl page which includes, but not limited to, the following controls.  If a user tabs out of the textbox, the saveOrSearchCPTRecord event fires.  But if the user types in the textbox and clicks directly on the Submit button, this important event does not fire.  I'd appreciate suggestions on how to handle this situation.  Thanks.

```
<input type="text" class="code required" data-bind="value: Code, enable: true, uniqueName: true, event: { keypress: $parent.searchCptKeyEvent, focusout: $parent.saveOrSearchCPTRecord}" />

<input type="button" value="Submit" data-bind="click: submitReview, clickBubble: false" title="Submit" id="btnSubmit" disabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Please provide the full code for an actual (but minimal) repro, and include which browsers have this issue. [I tried to repro](http://jsfiddle.net/d0pke1k3/) (and had to fill in some blanks while doing so), and get an alert in Chrome on Win 8.1 just fine.

Comment: @Jeroen I updated your fiddle to have the submit issue an alert. Interestingly, if I type and click Submit, the saevOrSearchCPTRecord fires, but the Submit alert does not appear. If I don't change the text, and click Submit, its trigger fires. Puzzling. http://jsfiddle.net/d0pke1k3/1/

Comment: Thanks for putting the little fiddles together.  In Chrome, the behavior is what I want...  click the submit button after entering some text, the saveOrSearch event fires first, click submit again, it submits.  But this is designed to support IE.  I can't even get the fiddle site to work in IE9.

Comment: Have you maybe tried the 'textInput' binding as opposed to the 'value' binding? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html